# "For $p > 0$" meaning for all $p$ or just one $p$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, expectation

This sentence:

> Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of random variables. Let $X$ be some other variable. Let $p>0$. Show that if $\sum _{n=1} ^\infty E |X_n-X|^p$ is finite, then $X_n \stackrel{a.s} \to X$.

Is the requirement that it holds for every $p > 0$ for there to be a.s. convergence, or just one $p > 0$?

I don't need help to solve the problem, just to understand what the theorem it wants me to prove is actually saying.

Comment: It's the same $p$ for all $X_n$, if that is what you are asking

Comment: If may theoretically be the case that $\sum E[X_n-X]^p$ is finite only for $p=42$. You still are asked to show a.s. convergence.

Comment: Fix an arbitrary $p > 0$. If $\sum E[X_n - X]^p$ is finite, then $X_n \to X$ a.s.

Comment: $\forall p > 0 \colon \left[ \sum_{n=1}^\infty E|X_n - X|^p < \infty \implies X_n \rightarrow X \text{ a.s.} \right]$

Answer (score 2):

It means that the statement is true for **all** $p>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Just one $p>0$, not all $p>0$. Simple reason is that all $p$th order moments may not even exist! If you require a solution to this problem, comment.